# How does `each_cons` work with single digits?

Tags: ruby

I've been doing [a kata on CodeWars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/jumping-number-special-numbers-series-number-4/train/ruby/5c2e25d8dd589339dfde7969), whose summary is to take a number and return `"Jumping!!"` if the digits are within 1 of each other (e.g. `2345`, `4323`, `7898`) and `"Not!!"` otherwise. All single digits (e.g. `5`, `7`, `9`) are jumping numbers.

This is one of the top solutions:

```
def jumping_number(n)
    n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2).all? { |x, y| (x - y).abs == 1 } ? "Jumping!!" : "Not!!"
end
```

This is my own code:

```
def jumping_number(n)
    n.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i).each_cons(2) { |x, y| return "Not!!" if (x - y).abs != 1 }
    return "Jumping!!"
end
```

I don't understand how `each_con` [sic] works. How can these methods' condition (correctly) return `true` when `n` is a single digit? The consecutive is either `nil` or `0` which, when used in the calculation, shouldn't return `true`, and yet it does.

Comment: The consecutive is neither `0` or `nil` (it does not exist at all). If you had one apple and I said give me 2 or them at a time, and I will only accept 2 of them at a time, or I won't accept anything, you would be stuck giving me nothing because it is physically impossible otherwise `['apple'].each_cons(2).to_a #=> []`.

Comment: "Every king of the USA is ..." is true whatever proposition you put in "...". The whole sentence is vacuously satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

Here is your misunderstanding:

> The consecutive is either nil or 0 which when used in the calculation shouldn't be returning true (and yet it is!)

It is neither `nil` nor `0`. It simply does not exist at all. The enumerator is empty.

Unfortunately, this is not documented in [the documentation of `Enumerable#each_cons`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons). The solution to your puzzle is that if the size you request for the cons is smaller than the size of the enumerable, then there will be no cons:

```
[5, 6, 7].each_cons(2).to_a
#=> [[5, 6], [6, 7]]

[5, 6, 7].each_cons(3).to_a
#=> [5, 6, 7]

[5, 6, 7].each_cons(4).to_a
#=> []
```

In other words: the block is never executed, therefore, there will never be an error.

Comment: ...and the other solution mentioned amounts to `[].all? {} #=> true` (when the array is  of size 1), which is why it works.

Comment: wouldn't it be nicer if ruby would return a nil element if size of the request is larger than the con ?

`[5, 6, 7].each_cons(4).to_a`
`#=> [5, 6, 7, nil]`

or at least

`#=> [5, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 1):

Your question has been answered by Jörg, but here's another way to perform the test.

```
def jumping_number(n)
  enum = n.digits.to_enum
  loop { return "Not!!" unless (enum.next - enum.peek).abs == 1 }
  "Jumping!!"
end     

jumping_number 5      #=> "Jumping!!" 
jumping_number 12321  #=> "Jumping!!" 
jumping_number 1243   #=> "Not!!"
```

Note that I've used [Integer#digits](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-digits) rather than [Integer#to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) to split out the digits:

```
123.digits                 #=> [3, 2, 1] 
123.to_s.chars.map(&:to_i) #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

The orders of the elements of the array produced are not the same, but that is no matter for this problem.

[Enumerator#peek](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek) raises a `StopInteration` exception when it is executed after [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) has caused the last element of the enumerator to be generated. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) then handles the exception by breaking out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is using [`Enumerable#chunk_while`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk_while) then measuring the size of the returned array.
How it works:

```
[1,2,3].chunk_while{ |x, y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.to_a #=> [[1, 2, 3]]
[1].chunk_while{ |x, y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.to_a #=> [[1]]
[1,2,4].chunk_while{ |x, y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.to_a #=> [[1, 2], [4]]
```

So, using it in a method:

```
def jumping_number(n)
  n.digits.chunk_while{ |x, y| (x-y).abs == 1 }.to_a.size == 1 ? "Jumping!!" : "Not!!"
end
```

(Thanks @Cary Swoveland for remembering that `Integer#digits` does exist.)